# Why didn't the remaining Balrogs rally to Sauron during the final battle for Middle-earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-silmarillion

Balrogs were servants of Morgoth, Sauron was a Lieutenant of Morgoth, Sauron commanded Balrogs under Morgoth, Sauron became head evil overlord after Morgoth's defeat. Sauron gathered all evil armies to himself in order to cover the world in darkness. Why no mighty Balrogs in the army? By most accounts there were still several lurking about in dark places.

Comment: Professional jealousy?

Comment: Do we know for sure there were any left?

Comment: No, we don't know for certain. Since the one was "awoken" or at least "aroused" by Sauron's rise, it seems reasonable to believe that any others would have too; and since no others seem to have awoken, my guess would be that there weren't any. I'd like to see the "most accounts" that say there were "several" around at the end of the Third Age.

Comment: @MattGutting I should have included the sources, sorry. They are available, even here at Stack. Will be offline for a few hours but will do that if no body does it before I get back.

Comment: Maybe they just said "Hell no, I won't go."  What's in it for them?  Morgoth, being a more powerful Valar, could order them around.  Sauron probably couldn't, at least without a lot of effort.  So if they're happily dreaming away the eons in deep mines or similar, why would they wake up?  The one Gandalf fought was previously awakened by the Dwarves, and seems to have had an attitude quite similar to mine if I'm rudely awakened.

Comment: There were only ever at most seven balrogs, though probably less. It's surprising enough that one managed to survive the War of Wrath.

Comment: I don't think Sauron awakened it. The dwarves woke it first. It sort of went back to sleep but much more lightly so Sauron could re-awaken it. The others were still deeply asleep so Sauron's power didn't wake them.

Comment: Related: [Why was the Balrog unconcerned with the fate of Middle Earth?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/33631/21267) and [After Gandalf kills the Balrog of Moria, do any more Balrogs remain in Middle-earth?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22495/21267) and [Was Durin's Bane a servant of Sauron?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64812/21267)

Comment: Durins Bane appears to have been the only active balrog since Melkors fall,but there's not much evidence of an alliance between him & Sauron.Certainly Sauron would have loved to have a balrog on his side,itd be almost unstoppable in the 3rd age.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They were scared as hell. Hiding away was what they were doing.

> some few that fled and hid themselves in caverns inaccessible at the roots of the earth; [The Voyage of Eärendil]

I do not think unless Melkor himself came back they'd have had the stones to show themselves. They, like Sauron, were Maiar.

> some great, as Sauron, or less so, as Balrogs. [Myths Transformed; Orcs]

They were peers but that does not mean they could not work with him, even as a subordinate in some way, such as Saruman.

Comment: If Melkor came back he would have been Morgoth anyway :-)

Answer (score 13):

Balrogs were Maia just as Sauron was.

Morgoth was a Valar, a more powerful being than a Maia.

Maybe Balrogs were happy to take orders from another Maia whilst both served under a Valar but once that Valar was no longer in charge they probably wouldnt want to take orders from someone they probably see as at most an equal.

Comment: I can see it now. Sauron approaches a Balrog; "I want you to be in my army  so I can rule the world".  Balrog; " I knew you before I became a Special Forces badass for Morgoth. You were a punk then and you're a punk now so go away so I can get some shuteye."